# My CSS displays differently in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: css

I'm developing on firefox, and I just wanted to check the current state how it looks in Chrome. And I saw a little problem. After that I checked it on Edge and on IE as well and the problem is in all browsers except firefox.

To show my problem, here's an image:

[As you can see there is no problem. A navigation bar positioned to the bottom of an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XT1Jg.png)

But in the other browser's they are look like this:

[You can see 2 or 3px difference. I don't know why. I'm using only two CSS file. The bootstrap-grid system and mine SCSS file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpFu.png)

I checked them out in Inspectors, FF says its height is 42px, while Chrome says 40.

SCSS:

```
nav{
top: 254px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
}
nav a{

text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: $nav-font;
font-size: 25px;
color:#126ADE;
letter-spacing: 0.8px;
margin-left: 20px;
padding: 5px;

}
nav a:first-child{ margin-left: 0px;}
nav a:hover{ background: white;}
```

Comment: Have you already checked in the inspector where do those 2 extra pixels go? My bet is that it has to do with the default CSS each browser uses.

Comment: @arielnmz

I've tried to check, and i don't know what is that 2px. https://i.imgur.com/5IN3dRx.png

I'm using margin: 0, and padding:0 as well.

Comment: Can you set "line-height: 32px;" and try again?

Comment: @Hanif I tried it, now the navbar's height is 42px in both browsers, but still there are two pixel difference somehow

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle version of your html code or a way somehow we can review your entire code? It may impact from other place.

Comment: A [MCVE] would be very helpful here. As you've tagged the question as CSS (as opposed to LESS) providing the rendered CSS would be helpful. Note that all relevant information should be included in the question itself, not an external resource. Links can die, or users may have pastebin firewalled by corporate rules

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ujurgcvj/1/

As you can see I'm using a little different numbers "top:290px;" because on jsFiddle it doesn't show the original state, I think its because of the lg screen. Anyway if you open this link in chrome and firefox you are able to see that pixel difference

Comment: btw, you shouldn't @import the fonts twice

Comment: @Facundo Corradini 
check the jsFiddle, I removed the two imports, also i noticed, that ignore those lines. I just saw them when I uploaded it to pastebin and already removed. It does not cause the 2 px problem.

Comment: @derx I know thats not the source for the problem, that's why I started the sentence with a "BTW"... anyway, I just wrote the right answer bellow. You should totally reconsider your HTML structure and go back to CSS positioning basics.

Comment: @derx To repeat, you are required to post a complete but minimal amount of markup that shows the problem within your question and NOT a jsfiddle. You have two votes to close your question and counting. [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In such a scenario, I try to use separate CSS rules for Firefox and Chrome:

Rules common to both browsers:

```
nav {
position: absolute;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
}
```

For Firefox alone:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
nav{
top: 252px;/*making the height same as chrome*/
}
}
```

Only for Chrome:

```
@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
nav{
top: 254px;
}
}
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Glad I could help, Welcome!!

Comment: This is a horrible answer. Chrome is not a webkit browser and this doesn't cover issues with IE and Edge! Even though it recognizes webkit vendor prefixes, that will not be true in the near future. So this solution is temporary and not sustainable as well as just being a bandaid over the real issue.

Comment: This problem commonly appears when absolute position is used. Thus every browser displays the exact change made to position, only firefox varies a little bit. Yes, this may not be permanent solution. But then, this works well for me in such situations, so i was sharing this solution.